# using numpy to store objects of different sizes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following task:

1. 2 lists. 1st list -> item, 2nd list -> meta data (2 floats) for every item.
2. These lists get changed by various steps of an algorithm, but their length is kept equal. i.e. their length increases, but increases equally. This way the index is a way to identify which item the meta data refers to.
3. At one (repeated) step of the algorithm I am shortening the list identifying the same items. Respectively, I have to tune the meta data list.

I could implement that using generic lists, but at some point it overloads the memory. So, I tried using np.array, but the issue with them is that their dimensions should be equal for every element. i.e. `arr=np.array([1,2, [3, [4]] ],dtype=object)` returns `arr.ndim=1`. What I need though is for it to return `arr.ndim=3`. I played around with it and discovered that `[3,[4]]` is of type `list` and has nothing to do with `np.array`. With equal dimensions for every element of `np.array`, it returns elements along every axis of `np types`, say, `np.int32` or `np.array`

Critical 3rd step. When I am going through the list and collecting meta data for the same items, I am putting them into the meta_list under the same index, i.e. creating (or expanding) a list of lists at that index. Example,

```
meta_list=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
```

Then, say, 1st and 3rd elements of the `item_list` are the same. So I have to combine their meta data. It yields this:

```
meta_list=[[1,2],[[3,4],[7,8]],[5,6]]
```

But I cannot wrap my head around how to implement this step using `np.array`, profiting from its storage efficiency as that `[[3,4],[7,8]]` element will be of type `list`. 
Would be very grateful for hints.

Comment: Arrays with dtype object are lists with an array wrapper.  Changing the size of a array, any dtype, produces a copy.  I doubt if arrays will save you memory.

Comment: @hpaulj What if I keep it a generic `np.array`, but 'split' it virtually with `np.nan`? `1x np.nan = '[' or ']'` `2x np.nan='[[' or ']]'`. That would be a representation for the `meta_list`. `[np.nan, 1,2, np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,4,np.nan,np.nan,7,8, np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,5,6,np.nan]`?

Comment: It creates an overhead in terms of having very many `np.nan`. But probably C-implementation of numpy more than compensates for that? I am just not that close to understanding the architecture, so it's difficult to make a sober estimate.

Comment: To store `nan` values the array has to have float dtype (8 bytes).  An array with shape `(1000,)` will have an 8000 byte databuffer, regardless of whether the values are 1, 1.234, nan, 1.234e342.

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj . What I meant as well is how much storage does an object in a list require in the ndarray. So that I could estimate an advantage of such approach. Do you know of an estimate?

Comment: `a.itemsize` gives the size of each of item in an array, e.g. 4 or 8 bytes for numbers.  An array of lists (dtype=object) just contains the pointers to those lists (which are stored else where in memory).  An array of lists is basically the same as a list of lists.